# RedirectToRoute is double-encoding the "/" in parameters that are URLs in the routeValues

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, encoding, routes

I have an encoding problem I can't seem to get to grips with regarding a parameter on a route. Basically, it either *never* URL encodes or it *double* URL encodes. I just want it single-encoded!

Here's the route I have registered:

```
routes.MapRoute("Scan", "Scan/{*url}", new { controller = "Scan", action = "Index" });
```

Now I have a controller action that redirects to that route. For simplicity's sake, let's say it looks like this:

```
var url = "troyhunt.com/search";
return RedirectToRoute("Scan", new { url });
```

The resulting URL is "Scan/troyhunt.com/search" - note that the forward slash after .com *has not* been escaped.

Now let's try that again but apply URL encoding:

```
var url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("troyhunt.com/search");
return RedirectToRoute("Scan", new { url });
```

This time the resulting URL is "Scan/troyhunt.com%252fsearch" - note that the forward slash has been double-encoded. If I set a breakpoint before the redirect I can see the UrlEncode method successfully encoding the forward slash into a %2f.

It appears that the redirect is encoding the "%" symbol but not the "/". If I test with other characters typically escaped with URL encoding (?,=), the encoding is working just fine directly from the RedirectToRoute method. Could this be an issue with treating the slash as separating route segments therefore not escaping? Am I missing something else here?

Update: more info, commentary and workaround is discussed in [To route or not to route, that is the question](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/09/to-route-or-not-to-route-that-is.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into System.Web.Routing it looks like this is happening due to the fact that route values are not URL encoded using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)` but in fact, are "escaped" using `Uri.EscapeUriString(value)`.

The offending code is in `System.Web.Routing.ParsedRoute`:

```
// Dev10 601636 Work around Uri.EscapeUriString not encoding #,&
    private static string UrlEncode(string str) {
        string escape = Uri.EscapeUriString(str); 
        return Regex.Replace(escape, "([#;?:@&=+$,])", new MatchEvaluator(EscapeReservedCharacters));
    }
```

This *could be* a by design decision (would have to ask the Microsoft folks about that), due to the fact that forward slashes are a fairly integral part of routes.   If it is I find it a little strange as the [documentation for `Uri.EscapeUriString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx) states that it's main usage as:

> Use the EscapeUriString method to prepare an unescaped URI string to be a parameter to the Uri constructor.

Following through the code that generates the route URL, it doesn't seem to use the `Uri` class at all - the URL is constructed and returned in a string.

If you passed this as a query string parameter, rather than as part of a specified route, it would be properly URL encoded (but would of course change the structure of your URL).